# Dependency issue in gradle when external project got included

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am getting following issue when I included external project in gradle (I am using Intellij IDEA).

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':build'.
> Could not find :<external-project>:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/<user>/.m2/repository//<external-project>//<external-project>-.pom
      file:/Users/<user>/.m2/repository//<external-project>//<external-project>-.jar
```

I have following line in settings.gradle:

include ':'
project(':').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../')

and build.gradle has: compile ':external-project'

individually both projects are working properly but when I am including external-project I am getting dependency issue.

Comment: try `compile project(':external-project')`

Comment: You are Gem, RaGe :) Thanks, its working now. If you can put this as Answer I can upvote and close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to refer to projects added in settings.gradle is:

```
compile project(':external-project')
```